Chrome & Chromium both refuse to run [FATAL:partition_address_space]
I spent 2 days trying to figure out why both chromium and chrome-linux won't start on my server from command line.
I also tried with multiple versions of both softwares, multiple combinations of fancy flags (--no-zygote etc.). There are no missing libraries (ldd chrome | grep not returns nothing). It works only if I run it as root as follows:
/home/my-user-folder/chrome-linux/chrome --headless --no-sandbox --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=/home/my-user-folder/output.pdf https://www.google.com 2>&1 | tee chrome-error.log

In return I get a PDF files with the content of google.com which is fine but if I run the same command not as root I receive the following:
[FATAL:partition_address_space.cc(77)] Check failed: false. 
#00 0x55b268094c82  (/home/my-user-folder/chrome-linux/chrome+0x924cc82)
#01 0x55b26809b443  (/home/my-user-folder/chrome-linux/chrome+0x9253443)
#02 0x55b26809b35c  (/home/my-user-folder/chrome-linux/chrome+0x925335c)
#03 0x55b2680a0737  (/home/my-user-folder/chrome-linux/chrome+0x9258737)
#04 0x55b2680a0cbd  (/home/my-user-folder/chrome-linux/chrome+0x9258cbd)
#05 0x55b2680ae508  (/home/my-user-folder/chrome-linux/chrome+0x9266508)
#06 0x55b2680a71df  (/home/my-user-folder/chrome-linux/chrome+0x925f1df)
#07 0x55b2680a6ad9  (/home/my-user-folder/chrome-linux/chrome+0x925ead9)
#08 0x7f89f37d25ef  (/lib64/libc-2.28.so+0x475ef)

I also looked into /var/log/messages to see what pops up in the log whenever I run chrome as user and here is what I get.
Sep 10 14:36:23 xxxxxxxxx kernel: traps: chrome[3587350] trap int3 ip:55e8901b7cad sp:7ffd344644f0 error:0 in chrome[55e88b0e3000+b896000]
Sep 10 14:36:23 xxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Started Process Core Dump (PID 3587352/UID 0).
Sep 10 14:36:23 xxxxxxxxx systemd-coredump[3587353]: Resource limits disable core dumping for process 3587350 (chrome).
Sep 10 14:36:23 xxxxxxxxx systemd-coredump[3587353]: Process 3587350 (chrome) of user 1005 dumped core.
Sep 10 14:36:23 xxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: systemd-coredump@63-3587352-0.service: Succeeded.

The server runs Cloudlinux & cPanel. I need to use chrome (or chromium) on an hosted website that as far as I know has all the required permissions. Moreover I also tried disabling CageFS, SELinux and removing all limits (the website/user in question has unlimited CPU, memory etc.) but nothing changes.

I don't know why, but it looks like that the file /lib64/libc-2.28.so needs to be on the same filesystem as /home/my-user-folder/chrome-linux/chrome. If they are already on the same filesystem, the filesystem might be damaged.

I just ran into the same issue.  In my case I was launching chromium from a subprocess.  The subprocess was launched with python and I was using the resource module to set a limit on memory usage and applying it in a :
def preexec():
   resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (mem_limit, mem_limit))
await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(cmd, preexec_fn=preexec)

Removing the preexec function fixed the issue.  I found this issue that clued me in.  Maybe whatever is launching chromium is setting resource limits?
